# Line wrapping in a TextCell within an extensible window

Tags: bugs, front-end, notebooks, output-formatting, cells

**Bug introduced in V9 or earlier and persisting through V11.3**.

> [...] I sent your comments and my test results to developers for analysis. 
>   I do not know when a correction for this will be available. [...]
>
> CASE:3838364

---

I need `TextCell` as it allows for `TextJustification` etc etc. Now, take a look:

```
content = Panel[        
  TextCell @ "test test test test test test test test test" 
, ImageSize -> {100, 100}
]

MessageDialog[content, WindowSize -> {All, All}]

MessageDialog[content]
```

[image]

So the dialog with `WindowSize -> {All, All}` breaks line wrapping. Additionally, default buttons are missing.

Is this a bug? Can I fix that still having `WindowSize -> {All, All}` and a `TextCell`? I don't want automatic or fixed window size but to allow the content to dictate the size.