# Automatically extend ChoiceDialog

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options, grid-layouts, dialog-window

Writing:

```
ChoiceDialog["I dati sui nodi sono già stati inseriti?", 
             {sì -> 0, no -> 1},
             Magnification -> 1.5]
```

I get:

[image]

while writing:

```
ChoiceDialog[ExpressionCell["I dati sui nodi sono già stati inseriti?", 
             ShowStringCharacters -> False], 
             {sì -> 0, no -> 1}, 
             Magnification -> 1.5]
```

I get:

[image]

Given that for some special needs I have to use this last structure, is there any way to automatically lengthen the dialog?

Thank you!

---

---

By doing other tests, I noticed that by writing:

```
ChoiceDialog[ExpressionCell["I dati sui nodi sono già stati inseriti?", 
             LineIndent -> 0, 
             ShowStringCharacters -> False], 
            {sì -> 0, no -> 1},
             Magnification -> 1.5]
```

I get:

[image]

while writing:

```
ChoiceDialog[ExpressionCell["I dati sui nodi sono già stati inseriti?", 
             LineIndent -> 1, 
             ShowStringCharacters -> False], 
            {sì -> 0, no -> 1},
             Magnification -> 1.5]
```

I get:

[image]

when I would like there to be no indentation but to wrap after "sono". How could I do?

Comment: what about `ChoiceDialog[ExpressionCell["I dati sui nodi sono già stati inseriti?", ShowStringCharacters -> False, LineBreakWithin -> False], {sì -> 0, no -> 1}, Magnification -> 1.5, WindowSize -> Full]`

Comment: Why not use Style instead of ExpressionCell? Also, to control where the linebreak occurs, you could use the option LinebreakAdjustments.

Answer (score 1):

> Given that for some special needs I have to use this last structure, is there any way to automatically lengthen the dialog?

The answer is to use `WindowSize -> {All, All}`. But it won't help because of the bug: [Line wrapping in a TextCell within an extensible window](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137092/5478).

So either you create your own `*Dialog` functions that will handle `All`, which is very annoying since they are already there...

Or you can fix the size of all dialogs for your application so they look consistent. Plus take care about proper linebreaks, see next section.

---

> [...]  I would like there to be no indentation but to wrap after "sono" [...]

If you want to control line breaks you need to play with `LinebreakAdjustments`.

But for common needs you can use predefined wrappers. If you want expr to 'behave' like text use `Text` or `TextCell`:

```
ChoiceDialog[
 TextCell["I dati sui nodi sono già stati inseriti? I dati sui nodi \
sono già stati inseriti? I dati sui nodi sono già stati inseriti?"], \
{sì -> 0, no -> 1}, Magnification -> 1.5]
```

And if you want a linebreak before `sono`, put `\n` just before it. Or use `Column` and friends.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
ChoiceDialog["Make a choice", WindowSize -> {933, 93}];
```

Comment: Never mind, I guess you want to wrap?